# codeigniter Internal Server Error when move to real server

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have this problem when move my codeigniter app to real server

error:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function result_array() on boolean in /helper/application/models/team_model.php on line 41

code:

```
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

whole code :

```
    function __Construct(){     
    $this->load->database();    
} 

function select_data($field , $table , $where = '' , $join_array = '' , $limit = '' , $order = ''){ 
    $this->db->select($field);
    $this->db->from($table);

    if($where != ""){ 
        $this->db->where($where);
    }

    if($join_array != ''){
        if(in_array('multiple',$join_array)){
            foreach($join_array['1'] as $joinArray){
                $this->db->join($joinArray[0], $joinArray[1]);
            }
        }else{
            $this->db->join($join_array[0], $join_array[1]);
        }
    }

    if($limit != ""){
        if(count($limit)>1){
            $this->db->limit($limit['0'] , $limit['1']);
        }else{
            $this->db->limit($limit);
        }

    }

    if($order != ""){
        $this->db->order_by($order['0'] , $order['1']);
    }

   return $this->db->get->result_array();
    die();
}
```

Comment: I think $this->db->get() is not what you expect, so you cant result_array() on it.

Comment: try using $thid->db->get()->result(); it will also gives result in array

Comment: it give me the same error

Comment: You have not put table name in get('tablename')

Comment: Also your file and class names should start with the first letter upper case only.autoload the database as well.

Comment: may be but why it works fine on local server?

Comment: Probably it is not working on localhost, I think error reporting is disabled. That's why you can't see any errors. Please add all code which is related with this line, so we can inspect.

Comment: updated post with code

Comment: return $thid->db->get()->result();

$thid?

Comment: where is     "return $this->db->get()->result_array();" this code in the whole code block ?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this, and it works for me based on my database. If it doesn't work for you, I'd need to know more about your database, and how you are using it. I ran it by going to /test, but maybe for you it would be /index.php/test. That depends on your config.

```
<?php if( ! defined('BASEPATH') ) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Testing the select_data method
     */
    public function index()
    {
        var_dump($this->select_data(
            '*', 
            'users', 
            ['username' => 'BrianG'],
            ['auth_sessions', 'users.user_id = auth_sessions.user_id'],
            1,
            ['users.user_id','ASC']
        ));
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function select_data( $field , $table , $where = '' , $join_array = '' , $limit = '' , $order = '' ){ 

        $this->db->select($field);
        $this->db->from($table);

        if($where != "")
            $this->db->where($where);

        if($join_array != ''){
            if(in_array('multiple',$join_array)){
                foreach($join_array['1'] as $joinArray){
                    $this->db->join($joinArray[0], $joinArray[1]);
                }
            }else{
                $this->db->join($join_array[0], $join_array[1]);
            }
        }

        if($order != "")
            $this->db->order_by($order['0'] , $order['1']);

        if($limit != ""){
            if(count($limit)>1){
                $this->db->limit($limit['0'] , $limit['1']);
            }else{
                $this->db->limit($limit);
            }
        }

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->num_rows() > 0 
            ? $query->result_array()
            : NULL;
    }

}

/* End of file Test.php */
/* Location: /application/controllers/Test.php */
```

Comment: i try it , it give me this error "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean "

Comment: Right after the line that starts $query, can you please die( $this->db->last_query() );

Comment: And public function _Construct should be lowercased __construct

Comment: And I changed so that order_by is added before limit, which I think is important for CI. Test it.

Comment: I just changed my answer to a full working example. I tested this on my database, and it worked good. You can see how I used it, and hopefully you will do some testing and see that it works.

Comment: not working , my hosting is on ipage.com .may be the problem from server

Comment: I hope my effort was helpful to you. At least we know it's not the code.